# PySimpleGUI Combo value return (Python GUI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, anaconda, pysimplegui

This has been driving me crazy and I'm pretty sure it's a very easy fix, regardless, I couldnt find any solution, please help.

I am trying to make a gui in python, where the content updates as different elements from a dropdown list are selected, in the start I made the content according to the first dropdown option, and defaulted to it.

Now when I open the gui, the content won't refresh according to what is selected, it stays the same.

Here is my code:

```
#importing necessary libraries and frameworks
from firebase import firebase
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#declaring required variables
firebase_url = "https://***********.firebaseio.com/"
bicycle_1_url = '*******'
bicycle_2_url = '*******'
bicycle_3_url = '*******'

#setting firebase object with url to database
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication(firebase_url,None)
lockStatus = firebase.get(bicycle_1_url,'lockStatus')
current_cycle = 1
#Setting the change status button to dynamic text
if lockStatus == 'locked' :
    label_change_status ='UnLock Bicycle'
else :
    label_change_status ='Lock Bicycle'


#Declaring theme for the UI
sg.theme('DarkPurple4')

#Making the layout of GUI window (Every square bracket represents a row)
layout = [
         [sg.Text('',size=(35,1))],
         [sg.Text('Cycle ID: ',size=(10,1)), sg.Combo(['CY001','CY002','CY003'],size= 
            (6,1),key='cycle_id')],
         [sg.Text(lockStatus,key='label_lockStatus')],
         [sg.Button(label_change_status,key='ChangeStatus'),sg.Button('Exit')],
 ]

#Declaring your window
window = sg.Window('Lock Status Changer', layout)

#declaring event loop for the window
while True:
 event, values = window.read()
 print(event, values)
 if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
     break
 if event == 'cycle_id':
     cycle_no = window['cycle_id']
     if cycle_no == 0:
         current_cycle = 1
         lockStatus = firebase.get(bicycle_1_url,'lockStatus')
         window['label_lockStatus'].update[lockStatus]
     if cycle_no == 1:
         current_cycle = 2
         lockStatus = firebase.get(bicycle_2_url,'lockStatus')
         window['label_lockStatus'].update[lockStatus]
     if cycle_no == 2:
         current_cycle = 3
         lockStatus = firebase.get(bicycle_3_url,'lockStatus')
         window['label_lockStatus'].update[lockStatus]
 if event == 'ChangeStatus':
     #Change the lock status of selected bicycle
     if current_cycle == 1 :
             if lockStatus == 'locked' :
                 firebase.put(bicycle_1_url,'lockStatus','unlocked')
                 lockStatus == 'unlocked'
                 label_change_status =='Lock Bicycle'
             else :
                 firebase.put(bicycle_1_url,'lockStatus','locked')
                 lockStatus == 'locked'
                 label_change_status =='Unlock Bicycle'
             
     if current_cycle == 2 : 
             if lockStatus == 'locked' :
                 firebase.put(bicycle_2_url,'lockStatus','unlocked')
                 lockStatus == 'unlocked'
                 label_change_status =='Lock Bicycle'
             else :
                 firebase.put(bicycle_2_url,'lockStatus','locked')
                 lockStatus == 'locked'
                 label_change_status =='Unlock Bicycle'
             
      if current_cycle == 3 : 
             if lockStatus == 'locked' :
                 firebase.put(bicycle_3_url,'lockStatus','unlocked')
                 lockStatus == 'unlocked'
                 label_change_status =='Lock Bicycle'
             else :
                 firebase.put(bicycle_3_url,'lockStatus','locked')
                 lockStatus == 'locked';
                 label_change_status =='Unlock Bicycle'
     
     #Updating the lockstatus to the window                                
     window['ChangeStatus'].update(values[label_change_status])

#closing window when loop ends
window.close()
```

What should I change for it to know that I have updated my selection?

Comment: try window[combo].Get()

Comment: @matanh oh I ended up tring this eventually and that does work, sorry for the late reply tho

Comment: when I look your code again I see that you can just replace  `window['cycle_id']` to `values ['cycle_id']`

Comment: Yeah ig I could, anyways this project is long over and I ended up just restructuring my UI to work around this. Thanks for the solution though

Comment: I have post this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [the variable list](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-values-variable-return-values-as-a-list) from `window.read()` :

Write `values['cycle_id']` instead of `window['cycle_id']`